# How to get band count from local raster file in ArcGIS Runtime

Tags: wpf, raster, esri, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-net

I need to know how to get the band count of raster file directly in ArcGIS Runtime with c# wpf. I am using the below code but it didn't get the Geo-Elements sometimes. Kindly suggest is there any other ways to get the raster band count directly?

```
        IdentifyLayerResult identifyResult = await MapViewModel.MapView.IdentifyLayerAsync(_rasterLayer, position, 0.001, false);
            if (identifyResult.GeoElements.Count != 0)
            {
                List<GeoElement> s = identifyResult.GeoElements.Distinct().ToList();
                GeoElement cell = identifyResult.GeoElements.First();
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> keyValuePair in cell.Attributes)
                {
                    string band = keyValuePair.Key;
                    if (band.ToUpper().Contains("BAND"))
                        bandCount = bandCount + 1;
                }
            }
```